# 2 identical classes in Java

Tags: java

Hi!

I have a small design problem in my current project. I have a class that holds the information about the time a Customer was in a Shop.

```
public class Customer {
    private String enterTime;
    private String leaveTime;

    public void enterTimeToInt {
        Integer.parseInt(enterTime);
    } 

    public void leaveTimeToInt {
        Integer.parseInt(leaveTime);
    } 
}
```

Now, in my program, i came across a situation where i had to make sure if there was any customer in the shop at a given time. Now, what i did was that i made another instance of the Customer class, which represented the given time and then checked if it matches any "real" Customer. But the problem is though, that i made a customer object representing time in a more abstract sense, not a customer.

What should i do in this case? I need exactly the same methods and variables as the Customer class has, but i don't think it is a good design choice to just make a Customer class that represents random time, not a specific customer's time.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you not simply add a comparison method for time to the `Customer` class? You pass the time to each object, and it returns `true` if it was in the shop at that time, `false` if not?

Comment: This sounds like a `Yes` or `No` question to me, what you need is a method of some other class, perhaps that class where you need this information and witch has knowledge about all customers witch checks for a given time (one single time) if at least one of the customers was in the shop.

Comment: i think this would do, in the class where you are creating customers instants you can create array of Boolean values, where a array item indicates a time slot.assign true to value if any customer was there at that time

Comment: Why are the times stored as String? Why not Date? Or Long (for milliseconds) or an int (not sure what your int would represent)

Comment: The class above doesn't represent a customer either. It only has an enter time and a leave time. BTW, why do you represent time as a String? And if you want the time as an int, why don't you use an int to represent it? Also, a given time would just be one time, not two, so why do you use this same class to represent a time? Show us more of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now, what i did was that i made another instance of the Customer class, which represented the given time and then checked if it matches any "real" Customer.

That's not what you want to do.

What you want to do is go through each customer with one time, and see if that time is between the `enterTime` and `leaveTime`.

Edited to answer the question:

I agree that the class is badly named.  The information is about a customer, so I named it `CustomerVisit`.

Your `CustomerVisit` class should look more like this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CustomerVisit {
    private Calendar enterTime;
    private Calendar leaveTime;


    public Calendar getEnterTime() {
        return enterTime;
    }

    public void setEnterTime(Calendar enterTime) {
        this.enterTime = enterTime;
    }

    public Calendar getLeaveTime() {
        return leaveTime;
    }

    public void setLeaveTime(Calendar leaveTime) {
        this.leaveTime = leaveTime;
    }

    public boolean isVisit(Calendar givenTime) {
        if (givenTime.after(enterTime) && givenTime.before(leaveTime)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setVisit(String visitString) {
        // File format is hh:mm-hh:mm
        String[] times = visitString.split("-");
        String[] enterTimeString = times[0].split(":");
        String[] leaveTimeString = times[1].split(":");

        enterTime = setCalendar(enterTimeString);
        leaveTime = setCalendar(leaveTimeString);
    }

    private Calendar setCalendar(String[] timeString) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 
                Integer.valueOf(timeString[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 
                Integer.valueOf(timeString[1]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return calendar;
    }
}
```

Instead of storing the time as a `String`, you need to store it in an object made for date / time calculations, like `Calendar`.

I was working on adding a `SimpleDateFormat` so you can display the `enterTime` and the 
`leaveTime` as a String.

With the `isVisit` method, you can loop through your `CustomerVisit` instances, and see which customers, or how many customers, visited at the `givenTime`.

The `setVisit` method takes the `String` from the file, and converts the `String` to `Calendar` objects.

Comment: @geekkid exactly what i said in my comment

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't mention it but, that's what i did actually. I didn't compare the two objects, i compared the objects' instance variables. But still, i need the time information to be stored in an object. Would it make sense if i get rid of the Customer class, and instead name it as Time. then i can use it for both, customer's time and random time (not associated with a customer).

Comment: @geekkid: As I said, it's not a customer. The best name would be Period, or TimeRange.

Comment: I read the customer times in a file where each row (representing one customer) is formatted like this: "12:04-14:15". In this case, i figured, it would be easier to represent times as String, and for comparison, just convert it to integer.

Comment: Somewhere in that file there has to be a date.  How else can you determine which day the customer visited from 12:04 to 14:15?  If there's no date, you can assume the current date.

Comment: No, there's no date. The program i'm working on is not an enterprise application , it's just a simple exercise from a programming competition.

Comment: @geekkid: always use the most appropriate type to represent your data. Only convert from/to string when reading/writing. This will be much cleaner, and more efficient. You don't want to convert each time you make a comparison, but only once, when reading the line. And if the line is invalid, you want to detect it as early as possible, when reading. Not when comparing with another time.

Comment: Why on Earth use an if/else in `isVisit()` when a simple `return givenTime.after(enterTime) && givenTime.before(leaveTime)` would do?

Comment: @Mac: Because the OP is new to Java.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: I really don't think that's a good reason. Why teach the OP to do the wrong thing, when you could be teaching them to do it the right way from the outset? It's not like doing it the right way is any harder to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need a new type of customer for this problem.

When you say time I presume you mean within a certain range.  I would do something like this:

```
public class CustomerRange  
{  
     Collection<Customer> customers;  

     ...   

     public boolean customerInShop(Date time)  
     {  
            for(Customer customer : customers)  
            {  
                  if(customer.getStart().after(time) && customer.getEnd().before(time))  
                  {
                      return true;
                  }  
            }  
            return false;
     }   
}
```

you need to update your Customer class like so:

```
public class Customer  
{  
     Date start;  
     Date end;  
       ...
}
```

As it stands currently, you have a dangerous API and one that doesn't work:

```
public void enterTimeToInt {
        Integer.parseInt(enterTime);
    }
```

One this doesn't return an int, which is what you most likely want to do.  Also, you have not defensively coded against the case that `enterTime` is not a valid integer.  Further most dates are treated as a `long`